# Header Files with Source Files C++

Tags: c++, file, header

I am trying to implement Header Files with Source Files using C++, but in the terminal the give me some errors.

Here is the code:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "add.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   cout << "The Sum of 3 and 4 is: " << add(3,4) << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

add.cpp

```
int add(int x, int y)
{
   return (x + y);
}
```

add.h

```
#ifndef ADD_H
#define ADD_H

int add(int x, int y);

#endif
```

Terminal Messages:
[image: Terminal Messages]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no one would know how to 'implement Header Files with Source Files using C++'

Comment: First, you need to `#include "add.h"` from `add.cpp`. Second, the error message you pointed is apparently more related to the way you invoke clang than to the code itself.

Comment: We need to see the command you used that produced the error. Also please edit the command and the error message into the question.

Comment: @jpo38, That include isn't necessary in this case, but it's recommended.

Comment: @Gabriel you have something wrong in your compilation command, you should inlcude it in your question

Comment: my compilation command that i am using is: g++ -o HeaderTest main.cpp add.cpp add.h

Comment: Why are the errors from clang if you're using g++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did use the C-compiler. The warning tells you that you provide C++-code to the C-compiler. In case you want to get rid of this warning, try clang++ -o add.o add.cpp followed by clang++ -o HeaderTest main.cpp add.o

Answer (score 1):

Your code in C++ is perfectly fine.
What you need is probably some adjustments in building.
You should either read on how to build, i.e. compile and link manually or use some IDE, or at least build system like Make, CMake, QMake etc.
If you want to do this by hand please provide command you have used to build this sample.

Comment: Thats the problem, i am trying to build it.

Answer (score 1):

Try `g++ -o add.o add.cpp` followed by `g++ -o HeaderTest main.cpp add.o`.